# Nginx dynamic proxy configuration

Tags: nginx

Below is a static config of what I'm trying to do.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name browser.shows.this.server.com;

  location / {
     proxy_set_header Host backend.server.com;
     proxy_redirect http://backend.server.com/ http://browser.shows.this.server.com/; 
  }
}
```

How can I make `backend.server.com` dynamic for each request? I'd like to pass the domain somehow **in the request**. Maybe in a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proxy_pass instead of proxy redirect. Hope this helps

alternatively can write a config like this

```
resolver your-server-ip;
set $upstream_endpoint http://your-url;
  location / {
     rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
     proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
   }
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass